# mdadm raid1 boot error "Create user root not found"

Tags: boot, server, raid, intel, mdadm

I created a RAID with Intel-Rapid-Storage(RST) - containing 2 3TB HDDs.
Then I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 64Bit. Everything worked fine and then I did a reboot.

Then I got the following error (repeating endlessly) while Ubuntu was starting:

```
incrementally starting raid arrays
mdadm: Create user root not found 
mdadm: create group disk not found
```

I rebooted the machine once again. Then a black screen was all i got (after selecting ubuntu from grub). I booted into recovery mode and selected `resume - resume normal boot`. Booting worked fine then. I did:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md126
```

The status shown was:

```
State : clean, resyncing 1%
```

So I waited until resync was finished and rebooted.
This is where I came back to the error message I described at the beginning of this post. `incrementally starting raid...`.

I do not have any idea how to fix this. Anyone out there had similar problems or may help me somehow?

Answer (score 1):

`md126` looks like a randomly made up md number that the recovery had put there, it's usually not the one in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

When a kernel is updated, it runs `update-initramfs` and `update-grub`.
They grab the md? numbers from

```
/proc/mdstat
/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

The numbers there have to be the same for initrd to boot.
Also, check in these files to see that all the `md?` and `UUID=` numbers are the same...

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
/etc/fstab
/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.
What I did to avoid this error is to edit the grub config.
Please try to modify as "nodmraid domdadm" after the "ro" description, and see if it works.